# Read from another CPU's memory without "asking" for it, (DMA)

Tags: memory, cpu, microcontroller, dma

I was thinking a bit about `DMA`.

Is it possible to read from a `CPU's memory` without having the CPU deliver it via some form of communication?

Like "`reversed DMA`".

The project for which I'm asking is a quadcopter control board, where I would like to access some values calculated by the main CPU or microcontroller, without asking it to send it to another microcontroller.

So let's say that the main CPU calculated the current angle in some direction, and puts it in its memory. I would then like to access that value (via another microcontroller) without taking up time from the main CPU. Is this possible?

Regards Daniel

Comment: Exactly what architecture are you using? This is going to be important. Raspberry Pi, Arduino?

Comment: I was thinking PIC32, I have no idea if they support such features, I know they have DMA though. Maybe ARM.

Comment: From what I understand that is a Motorola 4k processor based system. In theory if you are another device on the main bus you should just be able to access memory. This is what DMA is. In DMA the CPU tells another device to perform some operations and leave the results in a given patch of memory. There is no reason why, as another device on the bus, the CPU can't put some stuff in a region for you to read. As for how many devices can access the bus at once and if the architecture is cache coherent I don't know. You might have to check. You may have to flush the cache for the device to see it.

Comment: Transfer the data to an SPI memory chip so the second uC can get to it.

Answer (score 0):

Transfer the data to an SPI memory chip [(256K SPI Bus Low-Power Serial SRAM)](http://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/Devices.aspx?dDocName=en539039). Let the primary uC raise a flag to indicate that there is data in the chip to process. Then let the sedondary uC raise a flag to indicate that it is accessing the memory. Wire the 2 uC to the same chip however make sure the SPI is off after accessing is complete (preferably set the SPI pins to HiZ).